# Can ERC721TokenReceiver get address of which NFT contract it transfers from?

Tags: erc-721

As described in https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721, `ERC721TokenReceiver` captures 4 kinds of input arguments:

```
    /// @param _operator The address which called `safeTransferFrom` function
    /// @param _from The address which previously owned the token
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT identifier which is being transferred
    /// @param _data Additional data with no specified format
```

If I do a simple plain `safeTransferFrom` to transfer myself owned NFT address, then `_operator` and `_from` would both be my address.

MY Question is: Is it possible for `ERC721TokenReceiver` to get the NFT smart contract address during the context of handling `onERC721Received`.

For example, I would like to reject NFT_1 while accept NFT_2 in my contract. Where should I put the rejection logic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I just find the answer myself: `msg.sender` is the contract's address.